# Upgrading Prism 1X (Composite Application Guidance for WPF 1.0) to 4.X

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, prism

I am currently upgrading our prism assemblies to prism 4.X.
I've been relying heavily on this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921144%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#_Update_the_CompositeWpfEvent)!

One of the problems that I have encounter is the "WeakEventHandleManager", in old version it is referencing to Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands and I cannot seem to find the counterpart of it in the new Prism.

Anybody have encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

It is now part of the .NET Framework: [System.Windows.WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Although they both use WeakReference - the implementation is a little bit different. After further digging in the reflector, they made new WeakEventHandleManager as internal class in prism 4 which used to be public in prism 1. I made my own handling instead.